# Magento 2: Static block image upload not working

Tags: magento2, static-block, image-upload

I am using Magento 2.3 I am unable to upload image static block. It will show insert file instead of image.

[image]

I don't know what is the problem here

Comment: Is there anything in the magento log files?

Comment: Can you confirm that PHP has write permission onmedia folder

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I don't think it's file permission Problem because Image uploader needs to be show instead of file uploader

Comment: @where I don't see any log on this

Comment: @Magento2 you have checked default in luma theme working ?

Comment: I tried same problem there also

Comment: @Magento2 which php version you use ?

Comment: Magento latest version 2.3

Comment: Is there anything in the console? I see this error is shown by the `error` callback of the `$.ajaxSetup()` call from `lib/web/mage/backend/bootstrap.js`

Comment: which logs did you check? did you also check the webservers error-log?

Comment: @PhilippSander I upgrade Magento 2.3.1 after that i got 

500 Internal Server Error

Comment: http://localhost:8080/project/admin/cms/wysiwyg_images/contents/key/32eacd0b743ec1b1974aa4014e593f75b9127d17b6a6bac4b490e83e134dcad6/?form_key=DJBksYrx1iHoYUSq&node=root&isAjax=true

Answer (score 0):

If you're using apache watch the logs for your website. You should be able to find the file at `/var/log/apache2/<log file>` or `/var/log/httpd/<log file>`. Then in your terminal run the following command to watch for anything that is written to the file in real-time: `tail -f <path to log file>`.

If you get nothing from that next try your php logs. Those should also be located somewhere within the `/var/log` directory.

If you get any output about an error, please post it here so we can help you debug this.

Comment: I don't see any log on this

Comment: I try with fresh theme there also same problem File validation failed.

Comment: well are you using apache2 or nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Try below Solution

Go to `your-project-root\vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader.php`

And Find line no 552

```
if (is_array($file) && count($file) > 0 && count($file[0]) > 0 && count($file[1]) > 0) {
```

Replace With below  line

```
if (is_array($file) && count($file) > 0 && !empty($file[0]) && (isset($file[1]) && !empty($file[1]))) {
```

Than Reindex and flush cache.

Comment: No it's not working still same only

Answer (score 0):

There was a known bug where a file uploader was being used instead of an image uploader for parts of the backend in the 2.3.0 release. It was fixed in 2.3.1, so if you aren't already running that version an update might resolve it.

If you can't upgrade immediately, the bug is detailed in [Issue 19549](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19549) along with the fix - look for the comment by SoCal. Essentially, you'd need to manually edit 4 or 5 files so the javscript uses the correct form element.

---

Otherwise, if that doesn't work is there any output to the Javascript console? That might help narrow down the problem.

(That specific error wording implies an error generated in the javascript and logged out by the error handling defined in the bootstrap.js file. Unfortunately the code in the bootstrap file itself doesn't know anything about the actual cause or location of the error, so any other logged issues might help.)

Comment: I upgrade Magento 2.3 but still same issue

Comment: in console i got this http://localhost:8080/project/admin/cms/wysiwyg_images/contents/key/32eacd0b743ec1b1974aa4014e593f75b9127d17b6a6bac4b490e83e134dcad6/?form_key=DJBksYrx1iHoYUSq&node=root&isAjax=true

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error